# Shared library compiled by me won't load and error message is virtually useless

Tags: c++, linux, dll, shared-libraries

I'm write a Linux C++ app that uses shared libraries as plugins. (I'm going to use the term DLL here because .SO is too clumsy) The shared library system seems to be weak on error detail. Whenever there is a problem of any kind, the error is: **No such file or directory**, even though in every case the DLL file is there and strace shows my app opens the file.

```
Pcap.so is my code and it itself loads various other system DLL files.
open("./tls/x86_64/Pcap.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./tls/Pcap.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./x86_64/Pcap.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./Pcap.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)   = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200C\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0775, st_size=752011, ...}) = 0
getcwd("/home/woody/projects/wiregrep", 128) = 30
mmap(NULL, 2264832, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdb8cc88000
mprotect(0x7fdb8ccb0000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fdb8ceaf000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x27000) = 0x7fdb8ceaf000
close(3)                                = 0
open("./tls/x86_64/libtins.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./tls/libtins.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./x86_64/libtins.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./libtins.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=95890, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 95890, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdb8e128000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtins.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360~\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=465904, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2561000, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdb8ca10000
mprotect(0x7fdb8ca7f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fdb8cc7e000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6e000) = 0x7fdb8cc7e000
close(3)                                = 0
open("./tls/x86_64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./tls/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./x86_64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\356\5\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1930528, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4040856, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdb8c630000
mprotect(0x7fdb8c7e2000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fdb8c9e1000, 155648, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b1000) = 0x7fdb8c9e1000
mmap(0x7fdb8ca07000, 14488, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdb8ca07000
close(3)                                = 0
open("./tls/x86_64/libpcap.so.0.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./tls/libpcap.so.0.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./x86_64/libpcap.so.0.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./libpcap.so.0.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.0.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 L\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=249096, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2347480, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdb8c3f0000
mprotect(0x7fdb8c42b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fdb8c62a000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3a000) = 0x7fdb8c62a000
mmap(0x7fdb8c62d000, 472, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fdb8c62d000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fdb8c62a000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fdb8c9e1000, 110592, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fdb8cc7e000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fdb8e128000, 95890)           = 0
munmap(0x7fdb8cc88000, 2264832)         = 0
munmap(0x7fdb8ca10000, 2561000)         = 0
munmap(0x7fdb8c630000, 4040856)         = 0
munmap(0x7fdb8c3f0000, 2347480)         = 0
munmap(0x7fdb8ceb8000, 2661832)         = 0
write(1, "ERROR:Unable to load shared libr"..., 100ERROR:Unable to load shared library(2): Pcap.so No such file or directory at:Plugin.h_26
) = 100
exit_group(-1)                          = ?
```

This shows that it is loading its dependent DLLs and it does work when compiled as a static library into an executable. Why it fails toward the end is opaque to me. There's no indication of why it's being munpap'ed out of memory.

I've worked through several types of errors that cause this and they are all different (unresolved externals, no --export-dynamic in the main framework code that loads the plugins, etc). I got the the point where I first create a simple app using the DLL code in a static link, with a main statement just to be able to see the error detail prior to DLL'izing the code. This Pcap.so works fine as an executeable but won't load as a DLL.

I compile like this:

```
VirtualBox-3:~/projects/wiregrep$ make Pcap.so
g++-4.7 -std=c++11 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -Wno-deprecated -g  -I. -fPIC -Wl,--export-dynamic  -Wall    -c -o Pcap.o Pcap.cc
g++-4.7 -Wl,--export-dynamic -shared -o Pcap.so Pcap.o mylibs/libmm.a -ltins
```

The code that loads the actual DLL looks like this:

```
   void Load(const char* classname)
{
    if (classname)
        (SharedLibraryFilename = classname) += ".so";

    SharedLibraryHandle = ::dlopen(SharedLibraryFilename, RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_GLOBAL);

    if (SharedLibraryHandle == NULL) // does strerror implicitly in resultin g message
        throw Exception(LOCATION, "Unable to load shared library(%d): %s", errno, SharedLibraryFilename.c_str());
}
```

I'm not so concerned about this particular situation but having a better way to debug the opaque process that Linux uses to load the DLL.

I have several other similar DLLs that load just fine but I had to debug-in-the-blind to resolve the problems in each of them to get them to work.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Doh! RTFM. There is a function called "dlerror()" which gives better detail on why a dl* function fails. I abase myself.

ERROR:Unable to load shared library: ./Pcap.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI5Model